# CakePHP 2.x - Create a webservice with basic HTTP authentication

Tags: web-services, cakephp, authentication

Ok so I want to create a webservice which has a URL like:

http://www.website.com/webservice/update/

I then want to be able to post to this URL with an id and some authentication information. So that providing the authentication is successful, the id will then be passed to a function which will update my model.

I've read the documentation and it seems Basic HTTP authentication is what I need to achieve this. I'm just not sure of the best way to go about it though. Do I need to setup a separate controller for the authentication? or can I just handle it through my webservice controller?

How does the authentication data get passed through to my controller, is it through $request?

What's the best way to authenticate once I have the data?

UPDATE

Ok so here is where I am up to, I've setup Authentication for the controller, but allowed the views which I need to access.

The authtest method, sets up an HTTP socket to simulate a browser connection. Then the update method is supposed to check the username and pass that is passed in the request against my user model that I have setup.

I'm getting the following error though:

Call to undefined method AuthComponent::_findUser()

What am I doing wrong?

```
    <?php

    App::uses('AuthComponent', 'Controller/Component/');

    class PropertyController extends AppController {

      public $scaffold;
      public $components = array(
        'Auth' => array(
            'authenticate' => array('Basic')
        )
      );

      public function beforeFilter() {

        AuthComponent::$sessionKey = false;
        $this->Auth->allow('index','authtest','update');
        $this->Auth->unauthorizedRedirect = false;

      }
      public function update() {

        // Prevent header and footer from loading
        $this->layout = null;

        // Get Basic Auth - user and pass  
        $username = env('PHP_AUTH_USER');
        $pass = env('PHP_AUTH_PW');

        if (empty($username) || empty($pass)) {
           return false;
        }

        if( $this->Auth->_findUser($username, $pass) ) {
            echo "all good";
         }

        }
        public function authtest() {

            // Prevent header and footer from loading
            $this->layout = null;
            App::uses('HttpSocket', 'Network/Http');

            // Create HTTP Socket
            $HttpSocket = new HttpSocket();
            $HttpSocket->configAuth('Basic', 'Eddy', 'test');

            // Add post data
            $results = $HttpSocket->post(
                'http://local.webeservice.com/property/update/',
                'id=1992'
            );
            echo '<pre>';
            echo $results;
            echo '</pre>';

        }
        public function updated() {

        }   
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html

```
public function login() {
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    if ($this->Auth->login()) {
        //put your code here
        return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
    }
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
}
}
```

you can access the normal request data

Comment: Thanks, I had read that and the BasicAuth class reference but unfortunately I've not been able to piece together the correct functionality :(

Answer (score 0):

Use cake PHP HTTP socket

This is a sample code:

```
function update_stock_price(){
    $header = array(
        'header' => array(
            'X-EBAY-API-COMPATIBILITY-LEVEL'=>'903',
            'X-EBAY-API-DEV-NAME'=>'7994d18f-1c2b-46c5-bed8-decc651ef186',
            'X-EBAY-API-APP-NAME'=>'Directio-7da2-4081-b403-4aee455c2de8',
            'X-EBAY-API-CERT-NAME'=>'ee22b583-b57c-4bef-8eab-52b2e045d0e7',
            'X-EBAY-API-SITEID'=>'0',
            'X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME'=>'ReviseInventoryStatus'
        )
    );
    $HttpSocket = new HttpSocket();
    $final_array = array(
        'ReviseInventoryStatusRequest'=>array(
            '@xmlns' =>'urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents',
            'RequesterCredentials'=>array(
                'eBayAuthToken'=>'AgAAAA**AQAAAA**aAAAAA**+8N9VA**nY+sHZ2PrBmdj6wVnY+sEZ2PrA2dj6wFk4GhDZCGoA+dj6x9nY+seQ**GiUDAA**AAMAAA**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'
            ),
            'WarningLevel'=>'High',
            'InventoryStatus'=>array(
                'SKU'=>'S2730964',
                'ItemID'=>'110155417843',
                'Quantity'=>'6',
                'StartPrice'=>'200'
            )

        )
    );
    $xmlObject = Xml::fromArray($final_array);
    $xmlString = $xmlObject->asXML();
    $results = $HttpSocket-post('https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/ws/api.dll',$xmlString,$header);
    $xmlArray = Xml::toArray(Xml::build($results->body));
    pr($xmlArray);
}
```